# When $\lim\left| a_{k+1}/a_k \right| =1$ in the limit ratio test, does it follow that the series diverges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

In my lecture notes the theorem for the ratio test goes as follows:

> Let $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_k
>  \neq 0, \forall k \geq \hat{k} \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> (a) If there exists a $q \in (0,1)$ and a $k_0 \geq \hat{k}$ such
>   that:
>
> $$ \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| \leq q, \forall k \geq k_0$$
>
> then $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely.
>
> b) if there exists a $k_0 \geq \hat{k}: \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}
> \right| \geq 1, \forall k \geq k_0$, then $\sum a_k$ diverges.

Now the corollary for the ratio test in the limit case goes as follows:

> Let $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. If
>   $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| := q
> > \in \mathbb{R}$$ exists then the following two implications hold:
>
> a) if $q \lt 1 \Rightarrow \sum a_k$ converges absolutely
>
> b) if $q \gt 1 \Rightarrow \sum a_k$ diverges.

Why does q need to be greater than 1, so that $q=1$ would not be sufficient for divergence of the series? Because if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| =1$, then there exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0: \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| = 1$, which would cause the series to diverge by the first theorem. Can anybody explain this to me please?

Comment: If the limit is $1$, the quotient can be $< 1$ for all $k$. Consider $a_k = \frac{1}{k^p}$ for a fixed $p > 0$. The quotient is always $< 1$, the limit is $1$, and the series converges if $p > 1$ and diverges if $p \leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q=1$, the series might converge and might diverge. In this case, convergence cannot be determined by considering $q$ only.

In your discussion, you said that if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|{a_{k+1}\over a_k}\right|=1$, there exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$: $\left|{a_{n+1}\over a_n}\right|=1$. But this has a problem, since "converging to $1$" is same as "getting arbitrarily close to $1$", not "becoming $1$ if $n$ is sufficiently large". To be precise, as you know, by definition, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|{a_{k+1}\over a_k}\right|=1$ is same as: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that
$$\left|\left|{a_{n+1}\over a_n}\right|-1\right|<\epsilon\quad \forall n>N.$$
It is not same as your statement: yours is more stronger.

As Daniel Fischer pointed out, if $q=1$, the series might converge and might diverge.

Comment: "getting infinitely close to $1$" doesn't mean anything, and could be the source of much confusion.

Comment: @TonyK I edited. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists $k_0 \ge \hat{k}$ such that $\left|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| \ge 1$ for all $k \ge k_0$, then $a_k$ doesn't even tend to zero, so the series can't possibly converge.

If $\lim_{k \rightarrow  \infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| = 1$, then it is not necessarily the case that $\left|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| \ge 1$ for all $k \ge$ some $k_0$, and the series might or might not converge: consider $a_k = 1/k^2$ versus $a_k = 1/k$.